# How to change port number for IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, webmatrix

I am using Web Matrix 3 for practicing ASP.NET but I cant run any Web Page because of an error. When I run any page I got this message

> Port '44300' is already being used by process 'IIS Express' (process ID '820').
>
> Recommendations:
>   1. Try switching to port other than '44300' and higher than 1024.
>   2. Stop the application that is using port '44300'

I dont know how to change or swich port. Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because as it says, the port is being used already. What you should do is create the application in Sites > Default Web Site. This should let you run the application without any problems.